# Send selected range via email with htm signature by vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need to send selection range from excell by email and add signature from htm file. I have next code to send selection and it works well:

```
Sub Send_Selection()
'Working in Excel 2002-2013
    Dim Sendrng As Range
       Dim strbody As Range
    On Error GoTo StopMacro

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Note: if the selection is one cell it will send the whole worksheet
    Set Sendrng = Selection

    'Create the mail and send it
    With Sendrng

        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope

            ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
            ' some header text to the email body.
            .Introduction = ""

            With .Item
                .To = "dg@siz66.ru"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "My subject"
                .send
            End With

        End With
    End With
StopMacro:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

End Sub
```

Next I have code to generate mail with signature from html file:

```
Sub Mail_Outlook_With_Signature_Html_2()
' Don't forget to copy the function GetBoiler in the module.
' Working in Office 2000-2013
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim SigString As String
    Dim Signature As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    SigString = "C:\Users\d.gazdovsky\Downloads\sign.htm"

    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = strbody & "<br>" & Signature
        .display    'or use .Display
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub


Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

Now I need only to combine this macros to solve my problem. Please help me with it. Thanks in advance

UPD 1: I try thi code, but it give error..

```
Sub Mail_Outlook_With_Signature_Html_2()
' Don't forget to copy the function GetBoiler in the module.
' Working in Office 2000-2013
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Dim strbody As Range



    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Note: if the selection is one cell it will send the whole worksheet
    Set Sendrng = Selection & Signature

    'Create the mail and send it
    With Sendrng

        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope

            ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
            ' some header text to the email body.
            .Introduction = ""

            With .Item
                .To = "dg@siz66.ru"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "My subject"
                .send
            End With

        End With
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    SigString = "C:\Users\d.gazdovsky\Downloads\sign.htm"

    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        '.HTMLBody = Sendrng & "<br>" & Signature
        .display    'or use .Display
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub


Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

Comment: if you only need to combine them... then go ahead and try! I'm not sure what your question is exactly

Comment: Sorry, that dont exact describe problem.. write it in update

Comment: ok, what error are you getting? usually the more useful info you provide the easiest to understand your problem

Comment: Error: Run-time error '424': Object required. for string Set Sendrng = Selection & Signature